# JAXB 2.2.6 generates corrupted XML with partially closed tags

Tags: xml, marshalling, java-7, jaxb2

I am using, JAXB 2.2.6 with Java 7 update 76 to serialize objects to file (size 80MB) on local disk. The XML output format is UTF-8. My operation system is CentOS 6.3. From time to time I see that some XML elements partially closed, see the third item below (the element column1 is partially closed):

This usually happens after ~20 hours of intensive JAXB usage, without any relevant exceptions.

```
<create-item>
    <item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="genericGroupEntryItem">
        <xmlID>-5987260994489220191</xmlID>
        <item-id full-id="generic-group-entry[@dn='5824453118091914208']"/>
        <column1>146.185.204.211</column1>
        <gateway-status>
            <gateway-block-reason str-value=""/>
            <gateway-send-reason str-value="AlwaysInGw"/>
        </gateway-status>
        <parent>4725476808104611397</parent>
    </item>
</create-item>

<create-item>
    <item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="genericGroupEntryItem">
        <xmlID>-5987175959784878857</xmlID>
        <item-id full-id="generic-group-entry[@dn='-2315178527002837052']"/>
        <column1>94.181.23.248</column1>
        <gateway-status>
            <gateway-block-reason str-value=""/>
            <gateway-send-reason str-value="AlwaysInGw"/>
        </gateway-status>
        <parent>4725476808104611397</parent>
    </item>
</create-item>

<create-item>
    <item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="genericGroupEntryItem">
        <xmlID>-5987081327585374961</xmlID>
        <item-id full-id="generic-group-entry[@dn='-188747396585508342']"/>
        <column1>108.166.108.109</colu<gateway-block-reason str-value=""/>
            <gateway-send-reason str-value="AlwaysInGw"/>
        </gateway-status>
        <parent>-6672437912731396466</parent>
    </item>
</create-item>
```

I tried to look for any relevant bugs, like wrong buffer handling, but without success. Did anyone familiar with such phenomenon?

Comment: Looks like the same issue as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30066653/jaxb-generated-corrupted-xmlintermittent-file-during-marshalling-eventhough-va). There's also a bug report linked in the comments.

Comment: I read the described issue, look similar but without examples.

Comment: Yeah, but the comments mention: _Some xml tags are missing and some tags are incorrect. Means there are partially closed tags some tags are missing in the correct places._